# split newspaper columns in css like windows 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I'm building an interactive web app without scrollbar that looks like modern UI of windows 8.
I've used http://metroui.org.ua/ to build the layout.
But there's a problem, I want to buid  newspaper columns layout(may be 3), which's described here:

- When I add a block (a square or a horizontal retangle) , in 1 column is displayed as a linear layout(left to right, up to down). And the most important, when a column is full, the block will be added to the next column.
- I tried using 3 divs, but I cannot move the block to the next column automatically(not using javascript).

Can anyone give me some solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS3 provides a way of turning any HTML node's content into any number of columns. There are properties for controlling the number of columns as well as their width, relative height ("fill," or how the content is divided across the existing columns), gutter between columns, "rule" (dividing line or border), etc.

As a starting point, see the [w3schools.com CSS3 Multiple Columns](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_multiple_columns.asp) reference page.

However, as usual, IE alone among widely used browsers does not support the column- CSS3 properties.

One cross-browser solution is the [Columnizer jQuery Plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/).

Answer (score 1):

Its not to clear what your asking here in all honesty. The template link you gave is responsive and uses media queries, if you adding new columns to this layout, you need to understand how all that works, and I think the problem here is that you dont!?

Comment: I don't wanna add a column, i just wanna the block automatically adding   to the next column when the current one is full. That's all.